# how to replace string after submit

Tags: php, replace

When typing in textarea this:

```
<div>
```

After submit this should be stored as

```
&lt;div&gt;
```

in the DB. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To encode HTML use `htmlentities` and use `html_entity_decode` to decode it again.

**Encode**

```
<?php
$str = "<div>";
echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

Output:

```
&lt;div&gt;
```

**Decode**

```
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Output:

```
<div>
```

Comment: ok i understand, but this should work for all html angulars, so also for span, p anchors etc...

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
<?php
    $str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

    // Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
    echo htmlentities($str);

    // Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
    echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```